# ValueError with input and int

Tags: python

I am in an intro to programming class which is using zyBooks so I'm not sure (due to the way this interpreter works) if my problem is just me doing something stupid or just not working properly with the zyBooks thing.

Its asking me to do a basic user input string.  These are the instructions:

> Assign user_str with a string from user input, with the prompt: 'Enter a string: '
>
> Hint -- Replace the ? in the following code: user_str = ?('Enter a string: ')

I believe i've followed the instructions its given me but I'm getting this error. Thanks for any help!!!

```
1
2 '''Your Solution Goes here '''
3 user_str = int(input'Enter a string: '))
4 print()
5 
6 print(user_str)
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Exited with return code 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    user_str = int(input('Enter a string: '))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Hello!'
```

Comment: hello, welcome to stack overflow. Please post the code/error in the question itself as text. You can format code by highlighting a selection and pressing ctrl-k. See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). Also, probably worth checking out [ask] and [help] .

Comment: Thanks for the editing help!! I appreciate it!

Comment: `user_str = input('Enter a string: ')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot turn `Hello!` into an `int`. Get rid of the `int(...)` around input.

Note: You can turn strings into ints if the string is a valid number.

Comment: Thanks so much!  The tutorial was confusing because right before that it was talking about turning strings into ints and the second output had numbers in it so I thought thats what it was wanting.  Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Im a little confused with your question, so I will answer both interpretations I can make.

**If you want the user to enter a string** (ex: Hello World), you want to save it as a string in a variable, so omit the `int()` function that will try (and fail) to convert it to a integer:

```
user_str = input('Enter a string: ')
```

**If you want an integer** instead (ex: 231) the problem is that you are asking the user for a string, so a better solution would be:

```
user_str = int(input('Enter a number: '))
```

or:

```
user_str = int(input('Enter a integer: '))
```

The correct way for this case would be to try to convert it to a integer, and print a message if it fails (Probably you haven't seen this in your class yet):

```
correct_inp = False
while not correct_inp:
    inp_str = input('Enter a integer: ')
    try:
        user_str = int(imp_str)
        correct_inp = True
    except:
        print("Ups, this is not an integer, try again")
print(user_str)
```